# overflowed by 18 pixel flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

A RenderFlex overflowed by 18 pixels

Hello , I am new to flutter. I am doing some project with flutter and I had some problem with this Widget, When I add an FlatButton I have got Right Overflowed by 18 pixels. Can you help me?

My code :

```
Widget _drawFooter() {
        return Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Row(
              // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text(
                    '10 COMMENTS',
                    style: _hashTagStyle,
                  ),
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                      onPressed: () {},
                      color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                    ),
                    Text('Open'),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text(
                      'SHARE',
                      style: _hashTagStyle,
                    ),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text(
                      'OPEN',
                      style: _hashTagStyle,
                    ),
                  ),
                  /* FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text(
                      'Open',
                      style: _hashTagStyle,
                    ),
                  ),*/
                  //  Text('Open'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```

And this is the screenShot Error :

[image]

Comment: Replace `row`  with `wrap`

Answer (score 2):

you can use wrap instead of row. here is the code:

```
        wrap(
      children: [
        FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text(
                '10 COMMENTS',
                style: _hashTagStyle,
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                ),
                Text('Open'),
              ],
            ),
            FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text(
                  'SHARE',
                  style: _hashTagStyle,
                ),
              ),
            FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text(
                    'OPEN',
                    style: _hashTagStyle,
                ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        
      ],
    )
```

it's work for me. for more detail please visit this [site](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-wrap-widget-e1ee0b005b16).

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Row` with `Wrap`

```
Expanded(
        child: Wrap(
          direction: Axis.horizontal,
          alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text(
                'SHARE',
              ),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text(
                'OPEN',
              ),
            ),
            //  Text('Open'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

try SingleChildScrollView and space with SizedBox:

```
    Widget _drawFooter() {
            return SingleChildScrollView(child:
    Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Row(
                  // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Text(
                        '10 COMMENTS',
                        style: _hashTagStyle,
                      ),
                    ),
SizedBox(width: 20),
                        IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                          onPressed: () {},
                          color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                        ),
SizedBox(width: 10),
                        Text('Open'),
SizedBox(width: 20),
                      FlatButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text(
                          'SHARE',
                          style: _hashTagStyle,
                        ),
                      ),
SizedBox(width: 30),
                      FlatButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text(
                          'OPEN',
                          style: _hashTagStyle,
                        ),
                      ),
                      /* FlatButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text(
                          'Open',
                          style: _hashTagStyle,
                        ),
                      ),*/
                      //  Text('Open'),
                    ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
            );
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap `Row` with `SingleChildScrollView` widget.